# Navigation not working in scala in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, ide

Navigation for method, object, class not working in eclipse. I installed the plugins and individually installed scala eclipse as well, but no luck.

Can someone suggest the solution or suggest the best scala IDE (tried intellij too but no luck).

Comment: The eclipse plug-in is serviceable. Recently used update site to install on fresh neon install. What doesn't work for you exactly? On what OS?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. To help us answer your question you must provide more information. Exactly what is is that is not working? What OK, what eclipse version, what plugins are you talking about e.t.c.

Comment: @som-snytt: i have fresh neon only. check below scenario:                                 class A{    B objB= new B();     objB.methodB("foo");}      here, I want navigate myself to the implementation of the methodB. But in scala in eclipse IDE, I am not able to do.     Hope this clarifies.

Comment: @Cleared:  i have fresh neon only. check below scenario: class A{ B objB= new B(); objB.methodB("foo");} here, I want navigate myself to the implementation of the methodB. But in scala in eclipse IDE, I am not able to do. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Update the question instead of providing additional information in the comment-section, this way new readers can more easily answer the question.

Comment: Highlight the method and hit F3. Works for me from both scala and java class. You would need to post more info if it doesn't for you.